# Visitor pattern if you have very many node types

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

### What do we have?

A software system we are working on needs to exchange lots of data between components. The data is structured in what we call trees of variables. This data essentially is the interface between components. The C++ code representing a specific interface is automatically generated from interface descriptions. There are different underlying implementations for doing the actual data exchange, like OPC/UA, but most of the code is shielded from that. The important node types are those that store values and array of values, both of which can be instantiated for almost any types.

```
class node { /* whatever all nodes have in common */ };

class value_node : public node { /* polymorphic access to value */ };

template<typename T>
class typed_value_node : public value_node { /* type-safe access to value */ };

// imagine pretty much the same for array_node and typed_array_node
```

Consequently, the visitor base class used to traverse the nodes in those trees has functions to accept all integer types (signed and unsigned), all floating types, booleans, and strings, both for const and non-const nodes. (We currently plan to map enum types to int/string pairs, but nothing has been set in stone regarding this.) All of those overloads exists for values and for array.
At the moment, that's around 70 overloads:

```
class visitor {
public:
    virtual ~visitor() = default;

    virtual void accept(      typed_value_node<         char     >&)  = 0;
    virtual void accept(const typed_value_node<         char     >&)  = 0;


    virtual void accept(      typed_value_node<  signed char     >&)  = 0;
    virtual void accept(const typed_value_node<  signed char     >&)  = 0;

    ...

    virtual void accept(      typed_value_node<  signed long long>&)  = 0;
    virtual void accept(const typed_value_node<  signed long long>&)  = 0;


    virtual void accept(      typed_value_node<unsigned char     >&)  = 0;
    virtual void accept(const typed_value_node<unsigned char     >&)  = 0;

    ...

    virtual void accept(      typed_value_node<unsigned long long>&)  = 0;
    virtual void accept(const typed_value_node<unsigned long long>&)  = 0;


    virtual void accept(      typed_value_node<bool              >&)  = 0;
    virtual void accept(const typed_value_node<bool              >&)  = 0;
    ...


    // repeat for typed_array_node
};
```

In order to be able to actually work with this, we employ CRTP to make a visitor implementation call function templates of a derived class:

```
template<typename Derived>
class visitor_impl : public visitor {
public:
    void accept(      typed_value_node<char>& node) override
    {static_cast<Derived*>(this)->do_visit(node);}
    void accept(const typed_value_node<char>& node) override
    {static_cast<Derived*>(this)->do_visit(node);}

    // etc.
};
```

That makes dealing with just *some kind* of nodes bearable:

```
class my_value_node_visitor : public visitor_impl<my_value_node_visitor> {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void accept(const typed_value_node<T>&) {/* I wanna see these*/}

    template<typename T>
    void accept(const T&)                   {/* I don't care about those */}
};
```

### What do we want?

Beginning a new C++ software component in an application domain heavy with eletrical engineering, we have decided to employ a compile-time-checking unit library (aka "dimensional analysis library"). Unit libraries are great in that they employ the type system to check your code for correctness at compile-time. They do this by creating an almost unbound number of types, which encode not only the underlying built-in type (int, double,...), but also the physical unit (mass, energy), the scale (milli-, mega-), and some tag (active/reactive/apparent power, degree Kelvin/Celsius).

### What's the problem?

Tree nodes with the correct physical units can easily be generated from the interface description. But if values of unit types are stored in a tree node, this will make our visitor base class need thousands of overloads for accepting all the different node types used, prompting developers to add new ones whenever a node needs a unit not used before, or in a scale not used before. We could come up with some clever abuse of templates to generate all those virtual functions at compile time from type lists. However, when the question came up if the resulting virtual table size could become a problem, I started to wonder if our current approach really is still the best one to tackle the problem.

Common wisdom says that, if you have **many node types** and **few algorithms** to traverse them, you should **use virtual functions** in the nodes themselves. If, OTOH, you have **many algorithms** and **few node types**, you should use the **visitor pattern**. Common wisdom also says that, if you have many of both, you're screwed.

My feeling is that, so far, we barely fit into the few-node-types/many-algorithms drawer. With the type proliferation that comes with compile-time units, my guts say we become a pretty good fit for the many-of-either drawer instead. In short: we might be screwed.

### What do we do now?

Having been firmly tied to C++03 until the end of last year (the embedded world moves slowly), we certainly are not too familiar with a lot of the tools other C++ programmers have been using for almost a decade. So I am hoping we're missing an obvious solution here.

Or maybe we're missing something not so obvious?

Comment: Using the visitor pattern seems to be a good choice and the many algos + types is problematic. One good approach to satisfy the "open-closed principle" (to avoid modification of established code but allow extension to new types) is the use of "double dispatch".  https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor-double-dispatch 
This is a common trick for implementing syntax trees for compilers which have to deal with zillions of types as well.

Comment: @wcochran This *is* double dispatch. The question is how to sanely dispatch several hundred types.

Comment: @user253751 ok. Would using `std::variant` be useful to combine some types (can be used in conjunction with `std::visit`)?

Comment: 1. Maybe coalesce some groups of types to types that are more general. For example all signed integer types to long long, all floating point types to double, and so on. 2. For the unit library maybe this is the right place to consider a runtime one? -- The solution to problems here will ultimately be finding the right subset of things to shift from compiletime to runtime.

Comment: So, does that mean there's 15 different variations of each type with different SI prefixes, each with its own visitor entry? Yikes. It seems like that's a good target to simplify on - is there any interaction between them that isn't just "multiply to get them on the same scale"? After that, the number type might be a good target - are there any interactions there are aren't "cast one to the more precise type"?

Comment: @user253751: Yep, that's double dispatch. Spot on.

Comment: @Sopel @parktomatomi Yes, I have been thinking of not using a compile-time-safe unit class for the interface, too. If we use one where only the underlying built-in type is a template, and the actual physical property/unit (`power`/`W`, `energy`/`Wh`) and the scale (`kilo`/`mega`) is runtime-encoded, then we would need to do more runtime checks while reading from, and writing to, the interfaces, but it would only double the number of `accept` functions to ~150, rather than produce thousands. I am still waiting to see if there's another way that I am missing.

Comment: thinking about your comment on many / few nodes & algorithms - you need to have all algorithms programmed, there's no way around it. If the algorithm is somewhat selected by type (I mean the one that includes physical unit) and not the underlying type (integer and such), you need to encode that information somewhere. Did you consider an unordered_map from type to function(pointer) to do the dispatch? It's kind of virtual, but allows more flexibility on which algorithm binds to what. Underlying type conversion might be a pain though.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds this after years while being in a similar situation and wonders what we have done:

Nodes employing quantities of units are now derived from nodes of their underlying POD (usually `double`). Those nodes also provide virtual functions to determine the unit (an `enum`) and the scale (milli, kilo) of the quantity. For pure POD nodes these default to "no unit" and "no scale". The nodes derived from them storing a quantity override those to return the appropriate data instead.

So it is a mixture of compile-time safety through double dispatch (can't confuse an integer with a floating point) and checks needed to be done at runtime (does this have a unit attached?) which kept the number of overloads from exploding into thousands.

This means the number of units we can use is currently limited by an enum which lists all of them at compile time, but we found that this is acceptable in practice, where we currently use only about 2 dozen units. Should that ever become a problem, though, we could model it through a runtime unit type, employing a list of powers representing the basic units, just like the compile-time unit types do.